# Return 2(2) to 2*(2)

Tags: python

If a number is followed by "(" in a string:
How do I Replace it with number*(

Ex: input:"2(3+4)"
Output: "2*(3+4)"

Comment: If your expressions cannot contain functions (whose names could potentially end with a number), you could use a regular expression like `(\d+)\(` to extract that pattern and perform the replacement using the built-in `re` module.

Comment: Can you clarify what the issue is? Please see [ask], [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

to make sure that you replace only after digit you can loop over the string like this:

```
input = "2(3(8(12))+4)"

output = input
indices_to_insert = []
for i in range(len(input)-1):
    if input[i].isdigit() and input[i+1] == '(':
        indices_to_insert.append(i)
for iter,index in enumerate(indices_to_insert):
    output = output[:index+iter+1] + "*" + output[index+iter+1:]
print(output)
```

output:

```
2*(3*(8*(12))+4)
```

you can also use regex

Comment: This also turns `2/(3+4)` into `2/*(3+4)`

Comment: you write, fixed it

Comment: What if there are multiple "(" <br> Like "2(3(4+2))"

Comment: absolutely right, fixed this also in the edited code.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a regular expression substitution:

```
import re

s = '2(3+4)'
s = re.sub(r'(\d+)\(', r'\1*(', s)
print(s)
```

Prints:

```
2*(3+4)
```

[Regex Demo and Explanation](https://regex101.com/r/JMSw5c/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Or you can try a bit shorter code that uses `re`

```
import re

s = '12(3+4)+5(4+1)-3(2(6/(1+1)))'
for m in re.findall('(\d+)(\()', s):
    s = s.replace(''.join(m), '*'.join(m))
print(s)

'12*(3+4)+5*(4+1)-3*(2*(6/(1+1)))'
```